# Printing file.read() doesn't display file content

Tags: python, file, file-read

I am not being able to understand why `file.read()` behaves differently when I save it in a variable. Here is the illustration:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as file:
    content=file.read()
    print(content)
    print("------")
    print(file.read())
```

And the output is:

```
a
b

------
```

So, the last line of the code is not printing anything out.

Anyone care to explain why?

Comment: If you reverse the two methods then you'd get the exact opposite result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File objects are *streams*; reading from them advances a file position. Reading again won't reset that file position, and since there was no new data added to the file you get an empty string back.

Use the [`file.seek()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) if you need to reset the file position to the start:

```
file.seek(0)
print(file.read())
```

Comment: This also worked when I used f.readlines() and then f.read() for two different purposes. In order for it to work, I had to insert a f.seek(0) between the two otherwise the f.read() did not output anything.